# Google Monitoring AlertPolicies notification spam due to threshold duration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Working with GCP Monitoring, I want to set up an alert based on GCP Uptime Check metric.
My alert is working with a threshold above 1 for a duration of 1min.

My problem is that I am getting spam by notifications due to the short duration when the time serie is spiky.
But I do want to keep a short duration to get the first notification quickly.

i.e. In the following image:

I am getting a first alert notification at 8:21 (after 1min) over the threshold, Great!
But then I will get a resolved notification at 8:22, a new alert notification at 8:23 and finally a resolved notification at 8:28.

So I am getting 4 notifications when I would like to only receive 2.
I miss the option to set a threshold duration to fire an alert and another threshold duration to resolve the incident. For my case, I would set 1min duration to fire and only 10min to resolve it.

[image: GCP Uptimecheck]

Can someone help with this issue?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You've set an alert which message you if current UpTCH will be above treshold for 1 minute. So it reached treshold ~8:19 and you got notification at 8:21 (UpTCH was above treshold for 1+ minutes so it fulfilled your rule). Then you got resolve notification and then at ~8:22 again it was higher then treshold, you got another alert. Which 2 you want to get? Which notification option did you choose email, sms, mobileapp? Is it possible to provide step by step how did you configure this alert? Did you see [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#number-of-notifications)

Comment: I would want only the 2 notifications: 1 ALERT notif at 8:21 and 1 RESOLVED notif at 8:28. My concern is about the 1min duration. I want to keep it for 1min to be sensitive for receiving ALERT notif but then I would like to set a 10min duration to receive a RESOLVED notif. Meaning that what happened at 8:21 should not be notify since the threshold would not be resolved before 10min.

Comment: Please provide more details. How did you create alert policy? Which are your notification channels?  This is Metric or Uptime Check from GCP Alerting? How did you configure it (without private information), how many conditions do you have? From what I understand, it's working as expected. in [Trigger configuration](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#configure-trigger) doc, you have example with treshond 0.3 and 5 minutes.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS , Not sure you understand what I am asking, my question is more if it is feasible with GCP Monitoring, it does not matter about how the metric is set. But to give you more details about the alert policy: resource_type=uptime_check_url metric=check_passed, aggregator=count false,  period=1m, aligner=next older, threshold=any series above 1m, multi-condtions similar for different uptimeChecks, policy_triggers=any, notif=emails,sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you want with the GCP Alerting Policy.

To have a better understanding I would suggest reading [Alerting behavior](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth).

In easy words, `Period` in GCP Alerting Policy is:

> The alignment period is a look-back interval from a particular point in time. For example, when the alignment period is five minutes, at 1:00 PM, the alignment period contains the samples received between 12:55 PM and 1:00 PM. At 1:01 PM, the alignment period slides one minute and contains the samples received between 12:56 PM and 1:01 PM.

and `Duration` is time for how long the value is above threshold. However, there is another important message:

> A condition resets its duration window each time a measurement doesn't satisfy the condition. This behavior is illustrated in the following example:

If I understand based on your comments, you want to get `Alert` notif at 8:21 and `RESOLVED` notif at 8:28.

However, you set `Period` 1 minute and `Duration` also for 1 minute. Policy Algorithm recognized this as a 2 separate incidents as both fulfill all conditions. At the last minute, the value threshold was above the threshold.

- 1st incident: ~08:19:40 AM to ~08:21:05 AM - so duration when value was higher than threshold was higher than 1 minute (~ 1'25s)
- 2nd incident: ~08:21:50 AM to 08:27:30 AM - here duration when value was higher than threshold was also longer than 1 minute (~5'40s)

So both alerts were intended with your configuration. It's described in [Incidents for metric-based alerts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events)

> An incident is a record of the triggering of an alerting policy. Cloud Monitoring opens an incident when a condition of an alerting policy has been met. The incident contains information you can use to investigate the cause of the alert.

Feature which you are asking might be implemented in some 3rd party software monitoring tools but not here.

Only thing which comes to my mind is to change duration/period to reduce false positives.

There is a good video on youtube which explains Alerting Policy - [here](https://youtu.be/UjL-BlixJKY?t=339) since 5:39.

**In general:**

- Alerts are generated each time when condition/s is/are met, like mentioned in [Introduction to alerting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#how_alerting_works)
- You cannot have 1 alert with two occurred events. Each event will trigger an alert.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, thank you for your detailed response here, unfortunately that the result I found as well. I hope GCP Monitoring team could support this case by improving the duration window.